# use curl to upload to a site using cloudinary

Tags: php, curl, upload, cloudinary

I'm making a tool to upload picture automatically to site X. This site use Cloudinary to upload and store there picture. Can I use CURL or something else to upload to site X (I have an account on site X of course, and I was allowed to upload too). Has anybody done this before ? If CURL can't do this, can anyone give me some keywords for further research ?

Comment: You would be able to use curl. But it looks like they (cloudinary) have a php library that has done the hard work for you. Will just require setting some configs initiating the upload class and calling the right methods. check it out https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php

Comment: @JasonJoslin I've seen that library too. But unfortunately I have no access to site X's cloudinary account information. On site X there's a dropzone, when I drop picture there it will upload to cloudinary and return an URL to submit. Is there anyway I can "fake" the droping action by curl ?